# How can I see the contents of Solr/Lucene QueryResultCache?

Tags: caching, solr, lucene

I have a default configuration of query result cache in solr config xml:

```
<queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                  size="512"
                  initialSize="512"
                  autowarmCount="0"/>
```

As far as I understand this setting means that Solr will cache 512 last recently used query responses, or in other words 512 sets of result ids. This data will help Solr on same or similar queries. Some performance tests and other observations indicate that query cache does not work as expected or works poorly.

1. Is there a possibility to see which queries are cached at the moment?
2. If responses of queries `+product:apple` and `+product:cherry` are cached, will they be used to perform query `+product:apple +product:cherry` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not easily. I guess you could attach a debugger to Solr and try to inspect stuff until you find it, not sure how easy (and practical) that would be.
2. No, Solr will not do that. But if you were using filter queries instead of just queries. That would work. Filter queries and their cache (the filterCache) are typically the most important cache. So `q=abc&fq=product:apple&fq=product:cherry` would use both cached fq if they were cached before. Each filter query is cached separately.

Comment: sorry I didn't get what is q=abc when we search for products

Comment: q=abc is just an example, meaning the part of the whole query that is applied along with fq and does not go into a fq. For example if you look for apples that have 'smith' in the name: q=name:smith&fq=product:apple

Comment: thanks, I did not know what is filter query, reading the docs now.

Comment: one more question, will FQ mechanics speedup facets as well and if not are there any similar methods to do that?

Comment: fq will speed up any query where you filter out part of the docs, for later faceting for example. NOt used for the facets themselves. For faceting, docvalues are recommended, enable them.